# Crontab configuration not working in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I'm trying to work with crontab.

In `crontab -e`:

```
*/10 * * * * rm home/user/Desktop/myFile
```

trying to delete *myFile* at every 10th minute.

I enabled Crontab using:

```
/etc/init.d/cron start
```

and then: `sudo rcconf` to ensure that the service remains after rebooting but it doesn't work!

```
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo update-rc.d cron defaults
user@ubuntu:~$ /etc/init.d/cron start
[ ok ] Starting cron (via systemctl): cron.service.
```

Comment: Cron should already be running by default. It looks as if you are missing an initial slash in the pathname to the file you're trying to delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
*/10 * * * * rm home/user/Desktop/myFile
```

You forgot to add a slash at the beginning to make it an absolute path. As it is, it probably won't work.

It should be:

```
*/10 * * * * rm /home/user/Desktop/myFile
```

Comment: Alternatively `rm "$HOME/Desktop/myfile"` or `rm Desktop/myfile` (assuming cron uses the home directory as working directory) if it's the same user that runs the cronjob.